# Select de múltiplas tabelas com o mesmo ID no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

A intenção da query é selecionar todos os registros de várias tabelas quando o ID for igual ao passado no parâmetro, o echo da linha SQL exibe a query abaixo, os registros existem, mas não retorna nenhum.

A intenção é verificar em qual das tabelas está o registro que possui o ID do parâmetro enviado, mas as tabelas não tem relacionamento, possuem apenas registros que PODEM SER que exista o ID, não que possa vir a existir o mesmo ID em todas, e as tabelas tem a mesma estrutura, muda-se apenas os nomes dos campos.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
`ax_det` a, 
`ax_det1` ar, 
`ax_det2` ca, 
`ax_det3` im, 
`ax_dete4` mo, 
`ax_det5` na, 
`ax_det6` te, 
`ax_det7` tr, 
`ax_det8` ve 
WHERE 
a.`aw_token` = '834545' 
OR 
ar.`ar_token` = '834545' 
OR 
ca.`ca_token` = '834545' 
OR 
im.`im_token` = '834545' 
OR 
mo.`mo_token` = '834545' 
OR 
na.`na_token` = '834545' 
OR 
te.`te_token` = '834545' 
OR 
tr.`tr_token` = '834545' 
OR 
ve.`ve_token` = '834545' 
;
```

Comment: Mas o que relaciona as linhas destas 9 diferentes tabelas?

Comment: Essas tabelas possuem as mesmas colunas? A mesma estrutura?

Comment: as tabelas tem sufixos diferentes, e a intenção é só selecionar os registros, ambas possuem o mesmo id em tabelas distintas, a relação é o id, mas cada uma das tabelas não dependem das outras para trabalhar.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves não, só possuem id's iguais, mas tem estrutura diferente como colocado na condição WHERE.

Comment: Certo, e vc precisa de todos os dados de cada tabela?

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves não, apenas o campo do próprio id

Comment: Entendi. Edite a pergunta e informe isso, pois é relevante.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves já o fiz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me parece o caso de utilizar o `UNION`:

```
SELECT a.aw_token AS token, 'ax_det' AS tabela FROM ax_det a WHERE a.aw_token = '834545'
UNION
SELECT ar.ar_token AS token, 'ax_det1' AS tabela FROM ax_det1 ar WHERE ar.ar_token = '834545'
UNION
-- ... UNION com as outras tabelas
UNION
SELECT ve.ve_token AS token, 'ax_det8' AS tabela FROM ax_det8 ve WHERE ve.ve_token = '834545'
```

---

> [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)
>
> [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) is used to combine the result from multiple [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statements into a single result set.

Em tradução livre:

> [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) é usado para combinar o resultado de várias instruções [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) em um único conjunto de resultados.

Comment: nenhuma delas tem relacionamento uma com as outras, a semelhança é apenas o id que existem em cada uma delas, o UNION nesse cenário resolveria também?

Comment: Para utilizar o `UNION`, a sequencia dos dados retornados pelos `select` devem ser o mesmo tipo e na mesma ordem

Comment: a estrutura é a mesma, muda-se os nomes dos campos, editei a pergunta, desculpe por faltar esse detalhe. confere por favor.

Comment: @Sorack Deu certo, fiz como sugerido e retornou todos os registros. Obrigado!

Comment: @EliseuB. com a alteração de agora vai bater com o que você descreveu

Answer (score 2):

```
select ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_det`    a where  a.`aw_token` = '834545')  a, 
       ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_det1`  ar where ar.`ar_token` = '834545') ar, 
       ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_det2`  ca where ca.`ca_token` = '834545') ca, 
       ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_det3`  im where im.`im_token` = '834545') im, 
       ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_dete4` mo where mo.`mo_token` = '834545') mo, 
       ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_det5`  na where na.`na_token` = '834545') na, 
       ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_det6`  te where te.`te_token` = '834545') te, 
       ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_det7`  tr where tr.`tr_token` = '834545') tr, 
       ( SELECT campo_desejado FROM `ax_det8`  ve where ve.`ve_token` = '834545') ve
```

Comment: Havia tentado o AND também, mas não retornou nenhum registro mesmo existindo nas tabelas, no caso da query, ela está dentro de um looping, que passa um ID diferente mas não muda nada, apenas precisa verificar em quais delas está o id procurado.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, deixei passar um detalhe importante, desculpe.

Comment: Vi que conseguiu, mas segue outra solução através de subquery.

Comment: A subquery faz o mesmo que o UNION certo? Vou experimentar com os dois exemplos, assim aprendo mais um pouco, obrigado pela sua sapiência.

Comment: O resultado irá retornar em colunas, caso não existir o id, vem como null.

Comment: Criei uma segunda instrução e testei. Obrigado.